# Generating Symmetric Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Does anyone know how to generate random symmetric matrices whose minimum eigenvalue's multiplicity is at least 2?

thanks

Comment: Any such matrix is of the form $A=Q\Lambda Q^T$ with orthogonal $Q$ and diagonal $\Lambda$, such that the minimum diagonal entry of $\Lambda$ has multiplicity at least $2$. Generate such a $Q$ and $\Lambda$ randomly and you're set.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few ways that might work for your purposes:

**Option 1:**

First, generate a random symmetric $n \times n$ matrix $A$.  Then, generate a random unitary (orthogonal) $2n \times 2n$ matrix $S$.  The random symmetric matrix $M$ that you want can be computed as
$$
M = S\pmatrix{A&0\\0&A}S^T
$$
We will specifically only have eigenvalues of even multiplicity.

**Option 2:**

Take $S$ of size $n \times n$ to be unitary (or orthogonal).  Let $D$ be a diagonal matrix of (real) eigenvalues, generated with appropriate multiplicity.  Compute
$$
SDS^T
$$

---

A decent way to generate $S$ is as follows: first, generate a random skew-Hermitian (or skew-symmetric) matrix $P$.  Then, define
$$
S = \exp(P) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1{k!}P^k \approx \sum_{k=0}^N \frac 1{k!}P^k
$$
to find a sufficient $N$: if $\epsilon$ is your margin of error, it suffices to find an $N$ such that
$$
\frac{\|P\|^N}{N!} < \epsilon
$$
where $\|\cdot\|$ is any (multiplicative) matrix norm.